# Exporting data out of expired appexchange app

Tags: managed-package, appexchange

We have a appexchange app "Mission Control" installed in the salesforce org. The data from that app need to be exported.

Issue is that custom object belonging to that managed package do no appear in data loader/workbench because the package has **expired**.

Is there any way to recover such data?

Comment: Have you tried Setup > Data Management > Data Export?